# Nifi: Merging all of necessary flowfile in one shot with MergeContent Processor

Tags: merge, apache-nifi

This is the question about MergeContent processor in Nifi.
Currently, I need to combine all flowfiles with one particular attribute in one shot manner.

But what happens is since there are so many flowFile with the same attribute, 
the processor produces a few different flowfiles merged with the attribute, and those few should be combined into one big flowfile together.

Are they any ways to wait for all flowfile with same attribute to come into the MergeContent Processor and merge all of them at one time?

If not, what could be an alternative?

Comment: do you have count of files to wait for? or any other limit that nifi should wait for files with same attribute?

Comment: No I don't have count of files. It varies from time to time depending on size of input file. And input file is split by some tag (with EvaluateXQuery) to a large number of different flowfiles. So how many small files with same attribute value is unknown. Or can I know somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the "Minimum Number of Entries" and "Maximum Number of Entries" to suit your use case and increase the "Max Bin Age" to a suitable time.

You can refer all the properties for merge-content here : https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.MergeContent/index.html

Also, are you using nifi in a cluster or stand alone? Because the flowfiles in one node cannot be merged with the flowfiles in the other node.

For instance, if you're using a nifi cluster with 5 nodes, each having 10 flowfiles. After using the merge content processor, you will have 5 files.

Let me know if you need further assistance!

Comment: I'm using it in stand alone. But the problem is that one large input xml file (nested deeply as well) into one node will be split into the range between 1000 to 1500 different flowfile (flattened here) so that each flow file can be converted to csv. I am using MergeContent here to combine all of small csv flowfiles which share the same particular attribute. So, unfortunately I cannot set Minimum Number of Entries because the number of entries absolutely varies from file to file.

Comment: Then in that case, I think increasing the max bin age might be able to help. You can increase it to say 120 seconds. And along with that you can set your minimum number of entries to a higher number, so that you can be sure whichever condition gets satisfied first, will get executed

Comment: where do the flowfiles go after getting merged? if its hdfs, I think there is a workaround where you rename all the flowfiles using the "update-attribute" processor and then in the PutHDFS processor, you can use conflict resolution strategy as "append". This means that all the flowfiles with the same name will get appended to the same file in HDFS. (PS : I am not too sure of this and would recommend you to test it out once, make sure you set your footer as a blank line to avoid data getting appended on the same line).

Comment: Well, requirement is that Nifi pipeline needs to convert xml into csv for 1 second per file ideally, even not sure if it is possible or not. So I cannot set the max bin age to 120 seconds neither. Regarding to HDFS, since the new csv table has different number of columns, simply appending might not work. (Maybe need to implement customized script to union new table to the existing one)

Answer (score 0):

Before the MergeContent Processor you should configure your connector with a Load Balancing policy of "Single Node" so that you guarantee that only 1 node will process the defragmentation.